# create html file from pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I use maven.

I need to create an html file and polulate it from a xml file. I need to do it in pom.xml. I have the xsl file.

can anyone please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look the [xml-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) which support transforming from XML to whatever via XSLT.

Comment: i have downloaded xml-maven-plugin-1.0-sources.jar and xml-maven-plugin-1.0-javadoc.jar. do i require any more plugin? what i need to write in the pom.xml?

Comment: Why do you download the sources etc. ? Just use it as a plugin.